# Npm install or adding new packages failing in Angular 10

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-cli

I have tried to install dotenv in the angular project using

```
'npm i dotenv'
```

It is returning an error of dependency conflicting. I have added the dependency manually in package.json and it also shows the same issue. I am facing this issue while adding different packages to the application.

I have also removed all these packages, deleted node modules, and tried a normal
`npm install`. It returned a similar error for me and I am blocked from running my application.

[image]

Following is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "highcharts": "^10.1.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^3.0.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.16",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-intl-tel-input": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.52.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Angular Version :

[image]

Node Version : v16.18.0

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Yes, It didnt works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to install : **npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular**

then **npm i**
then
**npm install --save-dev dotenv**
Install it as a development dependency. This typically means it won't get deployed to production